# How to optionally match a group?

Tags: regex

I have two possible patterns:

```
1.2 hello
1.2.3 hello
```

I would like to match `1`, `2` and `3` *if the latter exists*.

[Optional items](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) seem to be the way to go, but my [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/iPMl6M/1) `(\d)\.(\d)?(\.(\d)).hello` matches only `1.2.3 hello` (almost perfectly: I get four groups but the first, second and fourth contain what I want) - the first test sting is not matched at all.

**What would be the right match pattern?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern contains `(\d)\.(\d)?(\.(\d))` part that matches a digit, then a `.`, then an optional digit (it may be 1 or 0) and then a `.` + a digit. Thus, it can match `1..2 hello`, but not `1.2 hello`.

You may make the third group non-capturing and make it optional:

```
(\d)\.(\d)(?:\.(\d))?\s*hello
          ^^^      ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iPMl6M/2)

If your regex engine does not allow non-capturing groups, use a capturing one, just you will have to grab the value from Group 4:

```
(\d)\.(\d)(\.(\d))?\s*hello
```

See [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/iPMl6M/3).

Note that I replaced `.` before `hello` with `\s*` to match zero or more whitespaces.

Note also that if you need to match these numbers at the start of a line, you might consider pre-pending the pattern with `^` (and depending on your regex engine/tool, the `m` modifier).